# Google Glass and data from sensors

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk, aero-glass

Based on what I've read, Google Glass supports most/all sensors, and existing Android APIs are available to access sensors on a mobile device.

However, the GDK (gdk.jar) contains only gesture and voice-related class files, which means that custom 'glue' code is required in order to render sensor-specific data (from the gyroscope, accelerometer, and so forth) on the Glass screen.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3):

tl;dr: Try it like you would on any other Android device, probably using [SensorManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html). It should just work. They're also covered in the [GDK documentation](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/location-sensors/index#sensors).

The API surface of GDK Glassware is not limited to the classes contained in the GDK Add-on. The GDK Add-on merely closes the gaps between the Android SDK and features that are unique to Glass. This means, in general, given a problem that isn't covered by the GDK library directly, just attempt the Android solution.